# Best practice for select or insert into

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I was looking for quite some time on whats the best way of selecting or inserting some data.

I have two tables:

```
ReportData: report_data_id(pk), source_id(fk), value1;
Source: source_id(pk), source_name(varchar250);
```

I am doing a bulk insert into the `ReportData` around 10k of rows at once, but I don't know which is the best way of getting the `source_id`, because not all of the sources are defined.

I was thinking that a good way is writing a function to which I send a source (which is a string) and if the source exist return the id, if not insert the source and then return the id. And then before the bulk insert I will add this into the `VALUES` `SELECT * FROM get_source('SourceString')`. This then on insert is going to query that function 10k times.

In my ReportData I have like 10 columns which are FK and on each I need to do the same thing as described above.

Is this a good way of doing what I described above?

Comment: @ypercube I just updated my question, the problem is that I have around 10 columns on which I need to do the same thing.

Comment: You can adjust Erwin's answer for 10 tables.